# How to Send message to Azure Service Bus Subscription Deadletter using Rest Api with deadletter Reason and Error Description?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I can't find an example of how to send a message to a Azure Service Bus Subscription DeadLetter using rest api.  It appears that the suffix for the endpoint should be /Subscriptions//$deadletterqueue.  However, I can't find an example of how to pass the deadletterReason, and the deadLetterErrorDescription.  Is it be as simple as passing those values as message headers?

Answer (score -1):

Messages are not sent directly to the dead-letter queue by the client code (REST API or any other SDK). Instead, messages are **dead-lettered** by the broker when `MaxDeliveryCount` is exceeded and no more attempts to process the message can be made. That's when the broker will move the message to the dead-letter queue with the reason.

Not that there are also less common reasons, such as the number of hops (forwarding), expired time-to-live, etc. `MaxDeliveryCount` is the most common scenario.

Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues) will help in addition to this post.

Comment: I beg to disagree with you sir.  You absolutely can deadletter messages on purpose.  For example, the .net core azure service bus sdk supports doing this: [subscriptionClient.DeadLetterAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken, deadLetterReason, deadLetterErrorDescription)]. In our case, we are deadlettering messages that violate a business rule (ie. a property is required that was not passed in the message).  We have a need to do the same thing for a client [Salesforce] that can not use the Azure .net core sdk.

Comment: To dead-letter you have to first receive the message. That is **not** the same as "sending to dead-letter queue". That's dead-lettering a message. Your question should be titled "How to dead-letter a message using REST API" then 

Comment: And if you ask the right question, here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20533304/59563

Comment: Hum....the answer is from 2013 and someone said it would be supported in the future.  From looking at the docs, it looks like seven years later, it is still not supported using a rest api. Can that be correct?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. The REST API documentation doesn't say anything about dead-lettering. JavaScript SDK has [added that functionality](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/pull/7960) recently.